# Windows Snipping Tool Replacement?

Tags: windows

Does anyone know of a good Windows Snipping Tool Replacement? I changed my programs file to a different drive and it hasn't worked since. lil help :)

Comment: We will need much more information to give good recommendations here – asking for "a tool like X" is never giving enough details, even if linked. You should always list your requirements explicitly. Please see [How to ask for an alternative to some software](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/48/185) and the questions linked to it for details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [GreenShot](http://getgreenshot.org). It's free and much more featured than the snipping tool

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Why not just copy that one program back to your C: Drive? Its location on my machine is `%windir%\system32\SnippingTool.exe`

Alternatively, press the Windows key to show the menu, and in the search box type "snipping". When it appears, right click on the icon, select "properties" and change the location to wherever you copied it to.

Answer (score 0):

[Windows XP Snipping Tool](https://xpsnipping.codeplex.com/)

I use this program because there is no Snipping Tool preinstalled on Windows XP.

Although designed for Windows XP, this application will run on any Windows that has .NET 4.
It's Compatible With:
Windows XP
Windows 7
Windows 8
Windows 8.1 Preview

Answer (score 0):

As per my answer to [this](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/677/software-to-capture-screenshot-in-dos-mode/6796#6796) previous question:

For screen capture, I don't think that you can beat [FastStone Capture](http://www.faststone.org/FSCaptureDetail.htm). It does what you want and sooooo much more.

It has become commercial, but the [last free version](http://www.321download.com/LastFreeware/page4.html#FastStone%20Capture) is still available.

That should do it, and it's the one that I use & recommend, but you will find other options at http://www.techsupportalert.com/best-free-screen-capture-tool.htm and you can record video with one of these http://www.techsupportalert.com/best-free-screen-session-recorder.htm