# Windows 10 Snipping Tool replacement for immediate snip?

Tags: windows-10, screenshot

Finally jumping in to Windows 10, and there are so many quirks I want to turn off or revert, I'm thinking I should use a different OS, lol

The Windows 10 Snipping tool changed 1 behavior and I'd like to revert it back to the way it used to work.  It no longer has an option to immediately capture when you start the tool.  I found this out the hard way.  It seems this is ["by design"](https://superuser.com/questions/568575/auto-snip-with-snipping-tool-windows-8?rq=1) (Why don't they ever think their designs are bad??).

In looking around, I have tried several replacements ([Greenshot](http://getgreenshot.org/), [Lightshot](https://app.prntscr.com/en/index.html), [DuckCapture](http://www.majorgeeks.com/files/details/duckcapture.html), [ShareX](https://github.com/ShareX/ShareX/releases/tag/v11.4.1), and [Windows XP Snipping Tool](https://xpsnipping.codeplex.com/)) and none of them offer this one feature I desire.  I looked at [FastSone](http://www.faststone.org/FSCaptureDetail.htm), but it's $20.  There are some other cool features to be sure, but the primary function I want is absent.

This is a major important thing to me because I still use older Windows OS's that behave differently, and it will drive me nuts.

Is there a setting I can change, or a replacement that is obtainable?  I like the featureset of the Snipping Tool circa Windows 7.  The only thing I might change would be the thickness of the border post-snip, but that's an icing on the cake request.

I looked at [this question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/19227/windows-snipping-tool-replacement), eventually found the [duplicate](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/506/free-windows-program-to-save-screenshots-immediately-on-a-key-press?noredirect=1&lq=1), and then found [another](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/163/tool-for-taking-screenshot-and-quickly-editing-it).  Seems that they are mostly the same suggestions, though for a different purpose.

I would like the software to be free, and preferably FOSS/Libre/etc.

Comment: +1 "
use a different os" :D

Comment: That defeats the point of learning the new OS. And its still easier to figure out than Linux :-\